# X is an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

[image: ![enter image description here]

for this I did $$ln(1) - ln(P(x^2 + 10x - 24 \geq 0 ) = ln(P(-12 < x < 2) = ln(1 - (1 - e^{-18}) + (1 - e^{108})) $$

When I put this into the calcuator I get error as the answer. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should  get $-ln P(X\geq 2)$ becasue $x^{2}+10x \geq 24$ iff $|x+5| \geq 7$ iff $x \geq 2$ or $x \leq -12$ and $x \geq 0$ in our case. Can you continue from here?

Note that exponential random variables are positive. You are missing this point in your calculation.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Would the answer then be -ln(1 - e^(18))?

Comment: The answer is $-ln [1-10e^{-9}]$.

Comment: Could you explain where the 10 and 9 come from?

Comment: Use $P(X<2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how you get 10. Isn't it $$(1 - 1e^{0}) + (1 - e^{-9}) = 1 - e^{-9}?$$

Comment: $P(X=0)=e^{-9},P(X=1)=e^{-9}\frac 9 {1!}$. If you add these two you get $10e^{-9}$.